# SELECT WHERE sql query Android question

Tags: android, sql, select, where-clause

I'm a complete newbie to programming and am having problems implementing a SELECT query with a WHERE year_id = 'a selected year variable' to display results in a list view. My code as shown below displays all entries stored in the database. How can I alter it to filter it down to a selected year within year_id as anything I try to do crashes my app? I have spent hours searching for tutorials and similar questions but am still lost as regards an answer.......would really appreciate some help

```
MyDBHelper mh = new MyDBHelper(this);
mDb = mh.getWritableDatabase();
mCursor = mDb.query("tracker", null, null, null, null, null,
    "category_name ASC");
startManagingCursor(mCursor);

int view[] = {R.id.categoryNameView, R.id.dataView, R.id.placeView, R.id.amountView};
String col[] = { "category_name", "date", "place", "amount"};

SimpleCursorAdapter ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.display_item, mCursor, col, view);

DisplayAllView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayDateListView);
DisplayAllView.setAdapter(ca);
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help with your SQL query if you don't post it?

Comment: @maple He did post the query -- this is a method on the Database class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the javadoc for [db.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

3d and 4th arg are

> selection A filter declaring which
>   rows to return, formatted as an SQL
>   WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE
>   itself). Passing null will return all
>   rows for the given table.
>   selectionArgs You may include ?s in
>   selection, which will be replaced by
>   the values from selectionArgs, in
>   order that they appear in the
>   selection. The values will be bound as
>   Strings.

So you would do something like

```
mCursor = mDb.query("tracker", null, 
          "year_id = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(year)}, 
          null, null,  "category_name ASC");
```

Comment: Cheers Heiko for your reply, much appreciated. I had a look at db.query already and tried something similar to your query which crashed this Activity. Once again when I replaced your sql into the code the Activity crashes the app. The Log is saying "450: ERROR/Database(412): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here" The only other code in the activity is the protected void onDestroy { super.onDestroy(); mDb.close();} Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong and why this error is occuring?

Comment: Just spotted Maximus suggestion of "year_id=?" which has done the trick! Thanks a bunch guys......Aaron

Comment: @Aaron I've just updated my answer to include the =? for others to be a correct example. Sorry for not getting it exactly right. But you figured it out :)